# Capability to edit post slugs

Tags: capabilities

I have a custom role that is allowed to publish articles (the only role allowed to publish). Everything works as expected except that the role cannot edit slugs. It can press 'edit', type anything, but on save it gets reset.

What permission should I add so this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If it's supposed to edit its own post only, make it with *author*'s capabilities. If it should edit posts of other users, as well, make it with *editor*'s capabilities.

### Case 1

```
function wpse_add_your_role() {
    $role = get_role( 'author' );
    if ( ! empty( get_role( 'your_role' ) ) ) { 
        remove_role( 'your_role' );
    }
    add_role( 'your_role', 'Your Role', $role->capabilities );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_add_your_role', 10 );
```

### Case 2

```
function wpse_add_your_role() {
    $role = get_role( 'editor' );
    if ( ! empty( get_role( 'your_role' ) ) ) { 
        remove_role( 'your_role' );
    }
    add_role( 'your_role', 'Your Role', $role->capabilities );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_add_your_role', 10 );
```

### Code location

In both cases, put the code in current theme's `functions.php` file. Once the new role is created, remove the code from `functions.php`, or comment out this line:

```
// add_action( 'init', 'wpse_add_your_role', 10 );
```

### Final notes

You can fine tune your role, using `$role->add_cap()` or `$role->remove_cap()` methods, according to your needs. In case 1, do not remove `edit_posts` capability. In case 2, do not remove, neither, `edit_posts` nor `edit_others_posts` capabilities.